# How can I have a ceiling light and separate fan on the same switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I have two ceiling lights in the bedroom on the same switch. I replaced one with a fan with no light. Now I can not turn the fan on without the light coming on.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

You must add another switch and wire and separate the fan wiring from the light.

or

Buy a fan WITH a light and remove the other light.